# Does swap() function works in iostream header?

Tags: c++, arrays, function, iostream, swap

```
   #include <iostream>
   using namespace std;
   int main(){
   swap(a[i],a[j])
   }
```

In this the swap function work automatically or I need to create a another swap function to solve this?

Comment: please show a [mre], what is `a`?

Comment: Are you asking if `#include <iostream>` is enough to use `std::swap`? If that is your question, then it may work on your system but you should include one of the headers that officially provides [`std::swap`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap) like `#include <utility>` so it can work on any platform.

Comment: does it work? what does your compiler say about it? It doesnt compile here: https://godbolt.org/z/az8WqPxf8

Comment: Where is the `a` variable declared?

Answer (score 2):

`swap` is not a keyword in C++ but rather a function from the C++ standard library. So to use it you need to bring in the function from the appropriate C++ standard library header. Unfortunately `std::swap` has been rather itinerant since it first made it into the C++ standard:

- Up to but not including C++11, you need to `#include <algorithm>`
- From C++11 you need to `#include <utility>`
- From C++17 you can `#include <string_view>` instead

Relying on the implicit inclusion of the header means you're not writing portable C++.

Comment: Hmm, I don't see a requirement in C++17 or C++20 that `<string_view>` provides `std::swap`. `<utility>` does define it.

Comment: @PeteBecker: It's not quite definitive (and I know you're an expert in the field), but see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap

Comment: @PeteBecker for what it's worth, it's also mentioned here.  https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/string_view

Comment: I see [a note](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/string.view.synop#1) at the end of `string.view.synop` that `swap` should be provided.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux -- Aha! Strangely worded, but, yes, that does seem to be the intention. ("are available" is lazy writing; it should be "shall be defined", to impose a requirement) ( and, just in passing, a "note" in standardese is non-normative, and marked "[Note ... ]". The text in question is not a note) Regardless, `<utility>` still works, and won't raise eyebrows.

Comment: @PeteBecker What is the appropriate way to refer to these footnotes then?

Comment: Confusing, isn't it? It's not a footnote; it's ordinary text. It's the first paragraph of actual text in that section; all that stuff that comes before it is code, and not numbered. That "1" in the margin is the paragraph number.